# Model type for filesize

Tags: python, mysql, django

What would be the best db/model type to store a file size, that may be up to 100GB?

I was thinking:

```
original_file_size = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Would this be the correct choice here?

Comment: 100GB is roughly 100 **billion** bytes, that's beyond 32-bit representation. 64-bit `BIGINT` does the trick though.

Comment: AN alternate approach would be to have 2 fields - one that stores the integer, and the other stores the order. Example: 222MB would be 222 in the integer fields, and MB would be in a charfield with limited choices (KB, MB, GB, TB, etc)

Comment: @karthikr,interesting, but it will be less efficient to compare the size of file. (It is doable, just not straight enough)